# dash on property in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I'm translating some code from js to coffeescript:

I got an issue with the compiler for an object property containing a dash character:

If I do this:

```
params = 
  fill: 'white'
  stroke: '#fff'
  'stroke-width': 2
  'text-anchor': y_label_anchor
```

I get a weird compiler error without any line number saying: Error: cannot have an implicit value in an implicit object.

If I do this:

```
 params = 
   fill: 'white'
   stroke: '#fff'
   stroke-width: 2
   text-anchor: y_label_anchor
```

I get Parse error on line 1234: Unexpected '-'.

I totally get that Coffescript doesn't want to mess with dashes in property names.
The thing is, I still have to figure out a way to convert this object so I can pass it to a library function in javascript.

**Anybody knows a way I can create this object in Coffeescript?**

Thank you

Comment: As seen [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:params%20%3D%20%0A%20%20fill%3A%20%27white%27%0A%20%20stroke%3A%20%27%23fff%27%0A%20%20%27stroke-width%27%3A%202%0A%20%20%27text-anchor%27%3A%20y_label_anchor) the first version works fine. Maybe the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thank you... nice utility. I thought that was the problem because that was my last change, but obviously the first version is good.